# CSS: How to force objects to stay inside container but allow full width background?

Tags: html, css

Here is the sketch to better explain what I am trying to achieve (red lines are the invisible container):[image]

I want objects in header and footer to stay inside the fixed width container, but allow header and footer to have background color filling full width of browser window. How do I do that?

Comment: You're going to need to provide some of the code you've tried whilst attempting this yourself

Comment: Try sharing your code for some help?  We wont do it all for you...

Comment: @Paulie_D: Personally, I'd say this question is a different question to the one you've marked as duplicated. Slightly different ways of tackling them.

Albert: I'd split your header, content and footer up in to grids and apply the background to the containing elements. Google CSS grids, that'll get you on the right track.

Comment: Which is precisely what the first answer says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to make the area represented by the red lines in your diagram a single element.

For each block:

- Set the background on a full width element.
- Put a width constrained element inside it.
- Put the content in the width constrained element.

---

Consider using a class to describe the constrained width element so you can reuse its CSS for each of the three blocks you have.

Comment: Thanks, that should do the job now. I was trying to make container a single element, but now I just split it in 3 separate fixed-width-containers.